# Share PR comments with team outside of organisation

Tags: github

We have a team outside of our organisation that is writing firmware for us. They have an internal source control that we do not have access to. They share code with us by sharing a zip file with a .git inside it and we recreate the repo in our internal source control.

We want to conduct an overall code review. This will likely take some back and forth, multiple comments on multiple lines and files of code.

Is there a way to comment internally in our source control, then share these comments to a zip file with this external team? Or is the only way to do this, by creating another source control that is shared between us and the external team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a GitLab account
- Add them to your organization as a developer
- Create a repository
- Have them add that repository as a "remote" to theirs, so that when they push, their commits also go to that GitLab repository.
- Then, do your collaboration via GitLab. It has a decent interface for creating Pull/Merge Requests, adding comments to code, and accepting them.